# Android XML alignment issues with variable line TextView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I am trying to align the top of a user avatar ImageView with the bottom ofLinearLayout that has a **dynamically changing height**. This height varies depending on how many lines of text are contained in the message when it is populated. There can be lines ranging from 1 to 20 depending on how long the message is.

[image: Populated with 1 line]
[image: Populated with 5 lines]

Each post is getting dynamically populated by the Fragment as items in a ListView comprised of many posts. I achieved the above screenshots by changing android:layout_marginTop to get the desired look, but a layout architecture that could handle this dynamically is what I desire.

I have also tried implementing this with a RelativeLayout, but could not achieve the desired behavior this way either. Additionally I tried a solution that relied on using an invisible dummy element with a height set programmatically by measuring the height of the LinearLayout after it is populated, but this did not work either and felt extremely hacky.

Is there an easy way to achieve this type of behavior with xml layouts? Would a Relative, Linear or Frame layout architecture serve best in this type of situation? This is one of those things that seems like it should be simple to implement in theory but has been giving me some major headaches...

Thanks in advance for any help! And please let me know if any clarifications would help.

**Here is the xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/post_avatar"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        <!-- This is where i'm changing the top margin -->
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/their_no_user_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/image_user_avatar_blank_medium" />

        <com.gloo.mobile.android.ui.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/their_user_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/background_discussion_secondary"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_name"
                style="@style/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="John Doe" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/post_text"
                style="@style/body"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Message" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you please know me briefly what you actually try to achieved ?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your post I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/lin_lay_msg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:text="John Doe" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/post_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/user_name" 
    android:text="Message  that is really long and goes on for several lines and keeps on going and going and going and going still going for a couple more lines to make sure it is super long" />

  </LinearLayout> 

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/their_no_user_image"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/lin_lay_msg"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/lin_lay_msg"
android:src="@drawable/default" />
```

I have left out the non essential stuff like style which you can just add in.
As long as you set the left margin of the LinearLayout to compensate for the width of your image (assuming the image width stays the same) this should work no matter what the size of the screen is.

However I'm still a bit of a novice with android so don't take my word for it, test it rather.

Update: So I have tested on both my phone and tablet. It seems to be working correctly.